# Map equilateral range to asymmetrical range (Hue to YIQ) in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, hsl

I need a function to map a range with 3 equally sized segments to a range with segments of unequal sizes. Like the table below shows:

```
      (Red is all one range)
/--------------------------------\
| Color | Hue Range | YIQ Range  |
|=======|===========|============|
| Red   | 0 - 59    | 0 - 149    |
| Red   | 300 - 359 | 851 - 1000 |
| Green | 60 - 179  | 150 - 736  |
| Blue  | 180 - 299 | 737 - 850  |
\--------------------------------/
```

The overall goal is to convert a hue to the YIQ range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mapping **is linear**, then formula for every range is rather simple

```
 Determine what range given value H belongs to
 Get HueMIn, HueMax, YMin, YMax for this range
 Y = YMin + (H - HueMin) * (YMax - Ymin) / (HueMax - HueMin)
```

for example, value H=100 is in the third range,

```
 Y = 150 + (100 - 60) * (736 - 150) / (179 - 60) = 347
```

Comment: Awesome, I was definitely over-thinking it.